# Custom fonts not working on tailwindcss in nextjs

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm testing fonts in a nextjs proyect with tailwindcss and the fonts do not work, it renders the default font.

globals.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@font-face {
  font-family: 'JetBrainsMono';
  src: url(/assets/fonts/JetBrainsMono.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Iosevka';
  src: url(/assets/fonts/Iosevka.ttf);
}
```

tailwindcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

index.tsx

```
import { NextPage } from 'next'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>test</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <main>
        <div>
          <h1 className='Iosevka'>
            Iosevka
          </h1>
          <h1 className='JetBrainsMono'>
            Iosevka
          </h1>
       </div>
      </main>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

I have other proyects where this way to apply a custom font works, but in this test i can't get it work!

Comment: In your index.tsx file, you are using `className='JetBrainsMono'`, but no such class is defined in your stylesheet. Maybe adding `.JetBrainsMono { font-family: 'JetBrainsMono'; }` to your stylesheet would solve the issue?

Comment: That's it, this works, thanks. It was very simple at the end haha. anyway i found another way to do it with this style={{
          fontFamily: 'JetBrainsMono',
        }}